# Dynamically Adding Vertices to a Line in Three.js

Tags: three.js

I figured out how to draw a line in threejs, the problem is that I need to dynamically add vertices to the line. When I add vertices to the line dynamically the scene doesn't update.

I've tried `geometry.verticesNeedUpdate = true`, which doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

EDIT: Using `BufferGeometry` and `drawcalls` you can now implement equivalent functionality. See [Drawing a line with three.js dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31399856/drawing-a-line-with-three-js-dynamically/31411794#31411794).

three.js r.71

---

Dynamically adding vertices to a line is not supported. As stated in the [Wiki](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/wiki/Updates):

> You can only update content of buffers, you cannot resize buffers (this is very costly, basically equivalent to creating new geometry).
>
> You can emulate resizing by pre-allocating a larger buffer and then keeping unneeded vertices collapsed / hidden.

three.js r.55

Comment: thanks.i guess i will just remove and re-add a new line each frame... just seems more inefficient

Comment: I think the point WestLangley was making was that trying to do it dynamically is basicaly as inefficient as just creating a whole new geometry in the first place, so it's not less efficient its the same.

Comment: I added all points to geometry by this line of code :
linegeometryX.vertices.push(new THREE.Vertex(new THREE.Vector3(x, y, z)));
how can I hide/collapse unneeded vertices?

Comment: You need to make a new post with your question.

Answer (score 5):

I ran into this a couple of days ago too. As WestLangley said, you can't do true dynamic geometry out of the box, but alteredq has a couple of strategies for 'faking it' and achieving the desired effect at https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/342.

In regards to your comment on the last answer, **don't** just remove and re-add a new line from the scene each frame - you'll (most likely) incur a massive performance hit. You need to use either the first or second of alteredq's workaround strategies.

In my app I used option 1 like this:

1. Create a THREE.Geometry object in advance and initialise it with as many vertices as you think you'll need (or otherwise a fairly high number of vertices). (You'll also need to hide them somehow before you want to display them - I set their positions to be off screen.)
2. Create a THREE.Line object with that geometry and add to the scene.
3. Now, when you want to add a new point to the line you'll have to index into the geometry object's vertices, find the last unused one in there, and update it - change the coordinates to the real ones, and set `geometry.verticesNeedUpdate = true;` (otherwise it thinks nothing changed). (See [How to do updates](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/wiki/Updates) on the wiki.)

I'm still ironing out the kinks on my approach, but that should at least let you get a line drawing on screen.

three.js r55

Comment: How do you prevent the points offscreen from connecting to the "real" points you want to render?

Comment: Max, this was a while back by now so I can't remember exactly, but I think I changed the colour of the points (or connecting lines) to the same as the background colour of the scene. So the connection is still there, but it's not visible.

Answer (score 2):

As WestLangley's answer says, you can't do that. Here is the admittedly hacky workaround I have decided to use:

- Allocate more vertices than I need by filling geometry.vertices with the starting point of my line
- As new points come in that I want to add, shift the contents of the array to the left and write the new point in the last array entry of geometry.vertices

Code:
To create a new line:

```
function createNewLine(startingPoint){
    var geometry = new THREE.Geometry();
    for (i=0; i<MAX_LINE_POINTS; i++){
    geometry.vertices.push(startingPoint.clone());
    }
    myLine = new THREE.Line(geometry, lineMaterial);
    myLine.geometry.dynamic = true;
    scene.add(myLine);
    render();
}
```

To add a point to the line:

```
function addPoint(myPoint) {
    myLine.geometry.vertices.push(myLine.geometry.vertices.shift()); //shift the array
    myLine.geometry.vertices[maxLinePoints-1] = myPoint; //add the point to the end of the array
    myLine.geometry.verticesNeedUpdate = true;
    render();
}
```

What you end up with then is a Line that has a bunch of points piled up on top of each other followed by the points you actually want to render.
I submitted an issue on the three.js git repository for a simpler solution to this problem.
https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/4716