# Three.js some faces not displayed after vertices and face recalculation

Tags: three.js, webgl

We're recomputing the vertices and the faces on a manually generated object. The first version of the object gets displayed fine, but after recalculation some of the faces are not displayed. Also, __tmpVertices on geometry seems to be wrong. We've tried tons of functions which are supposed to update the mesh, but we haven't figured out a working solution yet.

The two things we update on the geometry is geometry.vertices, geometry.faces and geometry.faceVertexUvs, nothing else. Afterwards we call these 4 methods:

```
geometry.mergeVertices();
geometry.computeVertexNormals();
geometry.computeCentroids();
geometry.computeFaceNormals();
```

unfortunately, without success: part of the new faces are not displayed, it actually seems like it displays just the amount of faces the previous object had, and not more.

We would definitely appreciate some help in this matter!

Kind regards
Roman and Patrick

Comment: Try this order: mergeVertices, centroids, faceNormals, vertexNormals

Comment: No luck, unfortunately. Right now it's the following order:
- generate geometry.vertices
- generate geometry.faces
- geometry.mergeVertices();
- geometry.computeCentroids();
- geometry.computeFaceNormals();
- geometry.computeVertexNormals();
Still part of the faces are not displayed

Comment: Are they displayed if you set material.side = THREE.DoubleSide? If not, can you provide a simple live example (http://jsfiddle.net) to demonstrate your issue?

Comment: Hello WestLangley. We've uploaded a work in progress here: [link](http://www.ck-game.com/temp/threejs/). After 2 seconds the mesh is recalculated and displayed, and the error appears. We already had it DoubleSided, changing it has no effect

Comment: Sorry, I can't debug your code for you. You look like you are making good progress. Don't give up.

Comment: Ok sure, I understand. If someone wants to try: the important part is in /js/RingeGeometry.js at the very bottom, at the end of the function buildRing(...). Thanks anyway for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to a previous post on stackoverflow ([Dynamically Adding Vertices to a Line in Three.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14840026/dynamically-adding-vertices-to-a-line-in-three-js)) changing the size of the content buffers is not supported. Therefore we'll just recreate the object itself when trying to change the amount of vertices/faces.