# update vertices in THREE.Line()

Tags: javascript, three.js

Im trying to dynamically rebuild some geometry inside a THREE.Line object in a simple three.js app but for some reason the update is not triggered. I've set the line as a dynamic object and I set the `verticesNeedUpdate` attribute to true every time I update the geometry and still the line doesn't update. Can anybody see what I'm doing wrong?

```
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// line
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


function build_line(length) 
{
    var vertices = [];
    for (i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(i * 2, 0, 0)); 
    }

    return vertices;
}


var line_geo = new THREE.Geometry();


line_geo.vertices = build_line(3);
line_geo.dynamic = true;

console.log(line_geo);


// simple
material = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({
    color: 0xffffff,
    linewidth: 1,
    linejoin: "mitre"
});


var scene_object = new THREE.Line(line_geo, material);

scene.add(scene_object);



// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// render loop 
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

var current_length = 3

var render = function()
{
    current_length += 1;
    line_geo.vertices = build_line(current_length);
    line_geo.verticesNeedUpdate = true;

    // draw!
    requestAnimationFrame(render);
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
}

render();
```

## edit

according to this post

[Adding geometry to a three.js mesh after render](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17842521/adding-geometry-to-a-three-js-mesh-after-render)

you cant resize the contents of a buffer only repopulate it. This page mentions you can emulate resizing the buffer by initialising the buffer oversized and keeping unused verts colapsed or hidden

https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/wiki/Updates

I'm not sure exactly how you'd do this, I cant see a visibility flag or collapse flag on the `THREE.Vector3` I'm using for verts. I tried just replacing the Vectors with nulls but that throws an error. Any thoughts how to achieve this?

Comment: See if http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17842521/adding-geometry-to-a-three-js-mesh-after-render answers your question.

Comment: @WestLangley Thanks for the link, I tried a few things with no avail, you can see in the post edit

Comment: @WestLangley That seems to be linking to this page if I'm not mistaken

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14840026/dynamically-adding-vertices-to-a-line-in-three-js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end , collapsed can be understood as "in the same place". (there could be other ways to understand it, though)

That would mean that you need to allocate the max length

```
var vertices = [];

function allocate_line(maxLength) 
{
    var vertices = [];
    for (i = 0; i < maxLength; i++)
    {
        vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0)); 
    }
}
```

And then

```
function build_line(length) 
{
    for (i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        vertices[i].x = i * 2; 
    }
    for (i = length; i <= maxLength; i++)
    {
        vertices[i].x = (length - 1) * 2; 
    }
}
```

That is, all the unused vertices set to the coor of the last used one.

This is of course a quick and dirty implementation to give you the idea..